# How to customize programmatically uitableviewcell subclass, which has a nib?

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I am using custom UITableViewCell with a nib file with name "MyCellNib",for example.
I my tableviewcontroller i register in viewDidLoad this nib like this:

```
    [_table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellNib" bundle:nil]
                  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath: it looks like this

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:              (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 cell = [_table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
 cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
 return cell;
}
```

As u see i dont use standart pattern like if(cell == nil) etc.(as we do it in iOS4) - regiserNib method can do it for us.

So, the problem: I need to write some code in the cell subclass.

in my custom uitableviewcell subclass the method

```
  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

is not called (i used it before to customizw the cell), but i need it to add some stuff on contentView programmaticaly..

Is there any way to customize my custom cell when it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
All this pre-stuff can be performed in -(void)awakeFromNib method